# using less to double all parameters values

Tags: less, mixins

I'm writing a lot of code like

```
.something {
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    @media @tablet {
        left: 20px;
        top: 40px;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to refactor it to some mixin?

```
.something {
    .somemixin({
        left: 10px;
        top: 20px;
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use a mixin for the common properties and take a input parameter as the multiplier like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ieqmz). Does this address your need?

Comment: I have many different attributes. left, top, width, height, font-size, margins, paddings. And there are many combinations of them in many classes. Basically everything with 'px' should be doubled for tablet screen size.

Comment: Using this method you should still be able to achieve it mate. You just have to use the `* @multiplier` wherever you are specifiying a pixel value. It should work for nested classes also like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ieqmz).

Comment: Yep, you will have to put a multiplier there: [gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/1ca235642ed574a990ef#file-26016192-less).

Comment: Btw, if it's really just "everything" doubled I would probably try `transform: scale(2);` instead (though I wonder what happens if you try `@media @table {body {transform: scale(2)}}` :)

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Yes, transform [doesn't work on inline elements](http://jsfiddle.net/hLuvxy4z/1/) and it doesn't affect the margin/padding etc also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing a ruleset to a mixin and have that mixin also take a `multiplier` as one parameter.

**Less:** (for version 1.7.0 and above that support passing rulesets to mixins)

```
/* wrapper mixin called with the common rules as a ruleset and a multiplier */
.somemixin(@rules, @multiplier: 1){
    @rules();

    @media tablet{
        .common_props(@rules,2);
    }  
}

/* sub mixin to create rules for each media */
.common_props(@rules,@multiplier){ 
    @rules();
}

.something {
    /* calling wrapper mixin with the ruleset */
    .somemixin({
        left: 10px * @multiplier;
        top: 20px * @multiplier;
        .some-other-class{
            bottom: 1px * @multiplier;
            font-size: 12px * @multiplier;
            padding: 0px 1px * @multiplier;
        }
    });
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/tijub)

---

**Less:** (for versions lower than 1.7.0 that do not support passing of rulesets)

You can achieve this by creating a mixin with all the common properties and have that mixin also take a `multiplier` as one parameter.

```
.common_props(@multiplier: 1){
    left: 10px * @multiplier;
    top: 20px * @multiplier;
    .some-other-class{
        bottom: 5px * @multiplier;
        font-size: 12px * @multiplier;
        padding: 0px 1px * @multiplier;
    }
}
.something {
    .common_props();

    @media tablet{
        .common_props(2);
    }
}
```

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/ieqmz)

Calling the mixin by setting the appropriate multiplier value as input parameter would generate the output as required.

Since, we are assigning the default value for the `multiplier` as `1` there is no need to pass a parameter for the base settings.

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.something {
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
}
.something .some-other-class {
    bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 1px;
}
@media tablet {
    .something {
        left: 20px;
        top: 40px;
    }
    .something .some-other-class {
        bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding: 0px 2px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems appropriate to me. That's quite a lot of boilerplate code (have to write "* @multiplier" everywhere), I thought that there might be a possibility to parse ruleset rule by rule and modify them, but probably it's not possible.

Comment: True mate. If there was a way to do, it would have been wonderful. But atleast as of now, I don't think there is any other better option.